# Local version of prestashop installation redirects to live url - probably due to cache

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to upgrade an existing webshop. So I've downloaded the files of a live PrestaShop (1.6.1.1) and the database as well. I've imported the database through phpmyadmin and edited the shop_url table (and set the domain to localhost) as well as the ps_configuration table where I set PS_SHOP_DOMAIN = localhost and PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL=localhost. I also commented out all the rewriterules in [.htaccess](https://gist.github.com/Flobin/1f9598f83d0f66f63a06a125fe43ad21).

I'm using MAMP to serve the webshop. However, when I navigate to localhost:8888, I am immediately redirected to the live webshop.

What I've found is that deleting the cache folder stops this, but then I only see the text: "It works!"—no PrestaShop.

I've also set debug mode to true in config/defines.inc.php.

Could anyone tell me what I need to do in order to be able to view my webshop locally?

Thanks!

Comment: check .htaccess file

Comment: @Vlasin forgot to add: I commented out all the rewriterules in the .htaccess file. This is it: https://gist.github.com/Flobin/1f9598f83d0f66f63a06a125fe43ad21